# Remove last string value of foreach loop

Tags: php, html, phpexcel

This is my code that reads data from a .xls fil and present it on website:

```
$s = explode("@@",$rowData[$x][6]); //read data from .xls file, @@ as delimiter
      foreach ( $s as $element )  {
       echo '<li> <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
       echo print_r($element,true).PHP_EOL;
         } //end foreach
```

This is how the .xls file look like
[image]

as you can see in the pic, the Resp & Req columns use '@@' as delimeter, and my foreach loop identified the last '@@' as a new line

[image]

I'm quite a newbie I can't figure a way to remove the last loop, thanks for helping in advance!

Comment: `array_pop($s)`

Comment: `unset($s[count($s)-1])`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the `unset` function.
Replace `$s = explode("@@",$rowData[$x][6]);` with `$s = explode("@@",trim($rowData[$x][6], '@@'));`